# How to change the logo in DocFX?

Tags: .net, github-pages, docfx

I want to change the logo in DocFX which appears on the top left.

I have replaced instances of logo.svg with my own logo.svg

In docfx.json, the directory includes my logo:

```
"resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

this is my template setup:

```
"template": [
      "default",
      "templates/singulinkfx"
    ],
```

Anyone know how I can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in docfx.json in the `globalMetadata` section:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_appLogoPath": "images/logo.svg"
    }
  }
}
```